# updating UITabelView cells efficiently

Tags: ios, swift, performance, uitableview, signalr

I'm writing this app that has a table view, showing data about stock market. The app uses SignalR ([this lib](https://github.com/DyKnow/SignalR-ObjC)) for updating the data in real-time. Each of the table view cells have 10 labels representing some information about the respective instrument.
As I said, the app works in real time and sometimes gets as much as 20 updates per second which need to appear on UI. Each of the SignalR notifications contain a string that after parsing it I know which row, and which labels on that row(not all of them are changed every time) need to be updated.
**The question is:** which of the following ways is better performance wise?

updating the model and then calling

```
    self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
```

getting a reference to that specific row and updating the labels with changed values:

```
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: i, inSection: 0)
    let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!

    if self.watch[i]["bestBidQuantity"].string != list[3] {
        let bestBidQuantityLabel = cell.viewWithTag(7) as! UILabel
        bestBidQuantityLabel.text = StringManipulation.localizeDecimalNumber(Int64(list[3])!)
    }
```

**one important thing to note is that** the cell in question may not be visible at the time of updating. As far as I know calling `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` updates the row only if it's visible, but I'm not sure about my second solution regarding out of the view cells.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're worried about updating cells that aren't on screen? If you're dequeueing a cell (as you should) in cellForRowAtIndexPath:, your cell will be dequeued and setup with the correct information (from your model) when it's needed.

When you get your SignalR notification, update your model from the notification. When the user scrolls, a cell will be dequeued and setup with the latest information from your model.

For cells that are already in view, I like the second option, but still update the model for when the cell goes off screen and needs to be set up again.

Have you also not created a UITableViewCell subclass? I recommend using a subclass with IBOutlets instead of viewWithTag. You can then include a function in your cell subclass to update it's UI components. Something like this -

```
class StockCell: UITableViewCell
{
    @IBOutlet weak var bestBidQuantityLabel: UILabel?

    func update(notification: SignalIR) {
        bestBidQuantityLabel?.text = notification.bestBidQuantity
    }
}
```

When you get a new notification you could do something like this:

```
updateModel(notification)
if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: ..., inSection: ...)) as? StockCell {
     cell.update(notification)
}
```

You can also reuse the update(...) function to setup cells from cellForRowAtIndexPath: